# I don't understand what [dcl.enum]/4 says in relation to the "enclosing enum specififer" highlighted below

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer

[[dcl.emum]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#4):

> If an *enum-head-name* contains a *nested-name-specifier*, it shall not
>   begin with a *decltype-specifier* and the **enclosing enum-specifier** or
>   opaque-enum-declaration shall refer to an enumeration that was
>   previously declared directly in the class or namespace to which the
>   nested-name-specifier refers, or in an element of the inline namespace
>   set ([namespace.def]) of that namespace (i.e., neither inherited nor
>   introduced by a using-declaration), and the enum-specifier or
>   opaque-enum-declaration shall appear in a namespace enclosing the
>   previous declaration.

I believe this paragraph is somehow related to the simple snippet below. But I can't understand what is this **enclosing enum-specifier** mentioned above. Note that both `S::E::i` and `S::i` below are *enum-head-name*s, but those two expressions contain no *enum-specifier*s !

```
#include <iostream>
struct S
{
    enum E { i = 1 };
};

int main(){
    std::cout << S::E::i << '\n'; 
    std::cout << S::i << '\n';
}
```

This code prints

```
1
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe this paragraph is somehow related to the simple snippet below.

It is not related to that snippet, because the enum-specifier `enum E { i = 1 }` does not contain a nested-name-specifier.

> Note that both `S::E::i` and `S::i` below are enum-head-names

Those are not enum-head-names. enum-head-names are only inside enum-heads which are only inside enum-specifiers. Those are simply qualified-ids, which consist of a nested-name-specifier and an identifier which names the enumerator.

An example of an enum-specifier whose enum-head-name does contain a nested-name-specifier, and to which the quoted rule applies:

```
    struct S
    {
        enum E : int;
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^          opaque-enum-declaration
    };
    enum S::E : int { i = 1 };
//       ^^^                  nested-name-specifier
//       ^^^^                 enum-head-name
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           enum-head
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ enum-specifier
```

Comment: Where is the *enum-head-name* in your example containing a *nested-name-specifier*?

Comment: According to your reasoning this code should compile `struct S{ enum E; }; enum S::E { i = 1 };` but it doesn't.

Comment: @Ayrosa See http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#2 enum-base is not optional for an opaque-enum-declaration of an *unscoped* enumeration.

Comment: That is [not correct](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#nt:opaque-enum-declaration)

Comment: @Ayrosa To reword for even more correctness: enum-base shall not be omitted from an opaque-enum-declaration of an *unscoped* enumeration (regardless of grammar).